# Set theory: product of family of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\prod_{i \in I}A_i$ where $\{A_i\}_{i \in I}$ is a family of sets. For a subset $B \subset A$, let $B_i=p_i(B)$ for each $i \in I$. Prove that $B \subset \prod_{i \in I}B_i$.

I am trying to prove this question. I am very confused because in $\prod_{i \in I}B_i$, the elements are functions but in $B$, the elements are not functions? How can $B$ be a subset of it? Any help would be appreciated..

Comment: what is $p_i(B)$? I assume you are letting $A = \prod_iA_i$?

Comment: @ALB I guess it is the $i$'th projection

Comment: What kind of things are the elements of $B$ in your understanding, if they're not functions?

Comment: Why are the elements of $B$ not functions? It's a subset of $A$ and $A$ is a product. (But maybe your definition of product (although I only know one) matters here in which case you better give it to us).
My suggestion: look at your favorite element of $B$ and check that it is an element of the product.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here $A = \prod_{i \in I}A_i$ and that $p_i$ is the projection onto the $i$th coordinate.

Let $f \in B$. Then of course $p_i(f) \in B_i$ by definition of $B_i$. But $f(i) = p_i(f) \in B_i$, so $f(i) \in B_i$ for all $i \in I$. Hence $f \in \prod_{i \in I} B_i$.